# Do not lock screen command

Tags: lxde, screen-lock, xscreensaver

I am running Lubuntu with LXDE and xfce power manager. I have set lock screen when going to sleep (suspend/hibernate) and I like it this way. However, I'd like that the screen does not get locked when I, for example, am running `play whatever mp3s` or have set an alarm (which won't be audible with a locked screen).

This "do not lock screen" works fine when I am watching films (with SMPlayer), so I know it's possible. However, I'd like a command for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Fedora but I believe that Lubuntu/LXDE still uses xscreensaver. If so take a look at xscreensaver-command, which lets you do a number of things with its remote interface.

For example --deactivate simulates user activity, so you could run that in a loop in the background once every minute or so with a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
    sleep 60
    xscreensaver-command --deactivate >/dev/null
done
```

Or, you could simply use --exit before whatever period you want to suspend locks, and then start it manually when you'd like it running again.

Comment: I am using xautolock, but yes, this will work.